# Cannot CollectionAssert equal a class which inherits ICollection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I have two objects of class PCBDataHelper (code below) which I would like to assert are equal as part of a suite of unit tests. However, I am unable to get the tests to pass.

```
public class PCBDataHelper : ICollection<string>
{
    //private List<string> pcbData = new List<string>();
    private readonly HashSet<string> pcbData = new HashSet<string>();
    private const int MaxItemLength = 16;
    private const int MaxNumberItems = 5;
    #region ICollection<string> Members

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        if (pcbData.Count == MaxNumberItems)
            throw new AIException("Max number of items reached. Cannot add item");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item) || item.Length > MaxItemLength)
            throw new ArgumentException("PCBData item must not be null and have max length 16!");

        if(!pcbData.Add(item))
            throw new AIException("Cannot add item, it may already exist!");
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        pcbData.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(string item)
    {
        return pcbData.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(string[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        pcbData.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return pcbData.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(string item)
    {
        return pcbData.Remove(item);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<string> Members

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return pcbData.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return pcbData.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When I use `Assert.AreEqual(obj1, obj2)` I get the following output:

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<...HADataFile+PCBDataHelper>. Actual:<....HADataFile+PCBDataHelper>.

Which leads me to believe it is a collection. However when run as `CollectionAssert.AreEqual(obj1, obj2)` I get the following pre-compile error:

> cannot convert from '...HADataFile.PCBDataHelper' to 'System.Collections.ICollection'

for both arguments.

Comment: `ICollection<T>` does not implement `ICollection`, so if you want to use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` then your class needs `ICollection` too.

Comment: Ah okay, my mistake. What is the difference?

Comment: `ICollection` is the older interface which was added before C# had support for generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) does not implement [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8), so if you want to use [`CollectionAssert.AreEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequal?view=mstest-net-1.2.0) then your class needs `ICollection` too:

```
public class PCBDataHelper : ICollection<string>, ICollection
{
    // snip - you need to implement the relevant parts here
}
```